# Java - End for loop at end of word

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to make a Minecraft Bukkit plugin, and it involves making hashtags and such. I have it so that when you do `#hashtag-goes-here` it'll highlight it. The only problem is, you must have another word after it (to have a space) for it to work. This is my code so far:

```
            try{
                for(int i = index; i < message.length(); i++){
                    String str = Character.toString(message.charAt(i));
                    String sbString = sb.toString().trim();
                    System.out.println(sbString);
                    if(str.equals(" ")){
                        str.replace(str, str + ChatColor.RESET);
                        String hName = sb.toString().replaceFirst("#", "").trim();
                        String newMessage = message.replaceAll("#", ChatColor.AQUA + "#").replace(str, ChatColor.RESET + str);
                        event.setMessage(newMessage);
                        logHashtag(event.getPlayer(), event.getMessage(), hName);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        sb.append(str);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new HashtagException("Failed to change hashtag colors in message!");
            }
```

**Edit:** (Already answered like, last year, I know; this is so that people who read this know what I was asking) My question was so that it could work in all situations that the hashtag could be found in. Thanks to [halfbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747804/halfbit) for helping me :)

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I need it to work if there's only one word, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find strings in a text and highlight them, then regular expressions can be quite useful. You might use code similar to the following:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HashTagColorizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String AQUA = "<AQUA>", RESET = "<RESET>";
        String message = "Aaa #hashtag-goes-here bbb #another-hashtag ccc";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9-]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message.length());
        int position = 0;
        while (matcher.find(position)) {
            sb.append(message.substring(position, matcher.start()));
            sb.append(AQUA);
            System.out.println("event for " + matcher.group(1));
            sb.append(matcher.group().substring(1));
            sb.append(RESET);
            position = matcher.end();
        }
        sb.append(message.substring(position));
        System.out.println(sb);
        // Aaa <AQUA>hashtag-goes-here<RESET> bbb <AQUA>another-hashtag<RESET> ccc
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your logic in the `if` on `sb`, do it in the else on the `str` (or in the `sb` after appending `str`, but you will repeat a lot of processing in the sections of the `sb` already processed).

You are welcome.

BTW:

```
str.replace(str, str + ChatColor.RESET);
```

does nothing because `String` instances are *immutable*